# Usage of Libsvm functions

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, libsvm

Can anybody please help me in using **svm_check_parameter** in libsvm. Libsvm manual states that *To avoid wrong parameters* **svm_check_parameter()** *should be called before* **svm_train**.
But I cannot get any examples on how to use it. Could anyone please provide me with some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter checking process is done in your `svmtrain.m` function already. You can check the original `svm.cpp` file, the function is defined inside:

```
const char *svm_check_parameter(const svm_problem *prob, const svm_parameter *param)
```

and various error messages are included in this function. The error will display if there is something wrong with your data or parameter settings, otherwise it will just `return NULL;` in the end. That's why you don't see anything shown when you ran `svmtrain.m` : your parameters are all set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! But is there any function which can decide which parameters to use for most accurate classification of Testing data. I am trying to classify multiclass dataset using libsvm. It is giving really low accuracy. However when knn classification is used results are very high. What libsvm parameters would closely mimick knn classification??